# How to write custom query in Mongo Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, repository, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-mongo

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;   

 @Repository    
    public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {

            @Query("{ 'firstname' : ?0 }")
            List<Person> findByFirstname(String firstname);

        }
```

I am using spring data jpa with MongoDB. I am able to save, delete or retrieve (all records) using repository.

I am trying to retrieve record based on a property value. (Custom Query shown above). This does not work.

Can someone help me in finding out how to write custom Queries in MongoRepository where I can pass a column value and get the matching rows.

EDIT:

Adding Code.

```
@Document/*(collection = "person")*/
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private Address address;
          // gettters and setters
}

@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl{

          @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

          public Person findPersonByFirstName(String firstName) {

        List<Person> person = personRepository.findAllByFirstName(firstName);

        System.out.println("** Data Retrieved **" );

        return person.get(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom query for this kind of query.

Following should just work (provided your field in Person class is "firstname" - is that righ?)

```
List<Person> findAllByFirstname(String firstname);
```

Does your query work from a mongo console?

Comment: I get this exception when I try your code.Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.createFrom(Ljava/util/List;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/query/Parameters;
 at org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.getBindableParameters(Parameters.java:234)
 at org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.assertEitherAllParamAnnotatedOrNone(Parameters.java:261)
 at org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.<init>(Parameters.java:84)

Comment: Seems for MongoRepository, bcoz the atttibutes are stored in "key":"value" pairs it doesnot work the way it works for Spring Data JPA with other DBs.Yes, this query works in console db.person.find({"firstName":"Rakesh"})

Comment: Try findAllByFirstName. Queries are case sensitive. The same for your custom query.

Comment: Tried that.. No luck. This is the link I followed to set up.  http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.0.0.M5/reference/html/

Comment: please provide code of your class person and code that is calling the repository and also make sure you are using objects from the right package (e.g. the query must be from org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository)

Comment: Strange, it should be working... turn on logging in org.springframework.data.mongodb package and see if the output helps. You should see something like "....MongoTemplate - find using query: { "firstName" : { "...someQueryText.."}}" ...

Comment: How do I enable logging in org.springframework.data.mongodb package ?